# How to prove: for all nonnegative complex numbers holds $\bigl|\frac{z}{|z|}-1\bigr|\leq\lvert\arg z\rvert$

Tags: complex-numbers

Because I try to prove this geometrically, I started drawing. I managed to draw $|z|$ and $\lvert\arg z\rvert$. I started to get confused because I don't know how to draw $\bigl|\frac{z}{|z|}-1\bigr|$ and here everything stopped for me. I got a hint that I should compare the length of arc of the unit circle with the length of a line between $\frac{z}{|z|}$ and $1$.

P.S. When would equality hold?

Comment: Well, just apply the hint... The arclength is the absolute value of the argument, that is, your RHS, and the length of the line is your LHS.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how to draw or what $\frac{z}{|z|}$ is.

Comment: You should rather try to view $z/|z|$ as the point on the unit circle with argument... well, $\arg(z)$.

Comment: `for all nonnegative complex numbers` What's a "***nonnegative*** *complex number*"?

Comment: I'm trying to explain it to myself, so please bear with me. This is a complex number (a point on a circle unit) which is divided by its own length. How can a point be divided by its own length? Is this even reasonable? Then I would conclude it's still a point on the unit circle. Is this ok? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @dxiv good question, I assumed it's neither -a+ib or a-ib.

Comment: @continuity Complex numbers cannot be compared for ***in***equality, so it makes no sense to speak of "*positive*" or "*negative*" complex numbers in general.

Comment: The point is $\left|\dfrac{z}{|z|}\right| = 1$ so $\dfrac{z}{|z|}$ is the point on the unit circle that points in the same direction as $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\arg z=\arg\frac{z}{|z|}$, so it is not restrictive to assume $|z|=1$.

Set $z=e^{2i\varphi}$, where $2\varphi=\arg z$, so 
$$
|z-1|=|e^{2i\varphi}-1|
=|e^{i\varphi}(e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi})|
=|2ie^{i\varphi}\sin\varphi|=2\lvert\sin\varphi\rvert
$$
Hence your inequality translates into
$$
\lvert\sin\varphi\rvert\le|\varphi|
$$

Comment: Very nice. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the point $z/|z|$ in the complex plane and $B$ be the point $(1,0)$. The left hand side is the length of $\overline{AB}$ and the right hand side is just the arc length of $AB$ in the unit circle. Hence you get the inequality. The equality holds if and only if $A=B$, namely $z=1$.

Answer (score 0):

As for equality, after converting to polar coordinates, we examine 
$$
2(1-\cos \theta)=\theta^2+4\pi^2k^2
$$
for $k$ an integer. By simple bounding, it is clear that $k$ must be 0, as the absolute value of the LHS is less than $4$. Then by inspection (or graphing) 
$$
\theta=0
$$
solves
$$
2(1-\cos\theta)=\theta^2
$$

As for the inequality, the other answers are fine. Also don't lose sight of the geometric intuition; the line between two points on a circle is shorter than the arc that connects them. Indeed, the line between two points is shorter than any other funky path you would like to draw.